# Website Homepage is loading, none of the other pages work

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, apache2, http-status-code-404

I was messing around with my website last night and everything was working great. I went to bed and when I woke up I found out that for some reason the website broke. Right now, our homepage loads in its entirety but none of the other pages load at all. I reverted my Apache2.conf and restarted the Apache2 service, and uninstalled an SSL cert I was messing with the prior night but neither of those fixed it even though as far as I know it's in the same state it was last night when it was working in it's entirety.

When I go to a page that's not the homepage I get the error:

> The requested URL /css/site.css was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This happens for literally any page that's not the homepage. Like I said I didn't change my .htaccess, reverted my apache2 configuration, and undid what I was messing with last night but still cannot figure out why I'm getting this message. Any help is immensely appreciated, I can add any necessary details to this question.

EDIT: Should've specified it's not just a CSS error. For example, trying to access the 'login' page on my website gives the error:

> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I did not have this problem for the past week and I'm not sure why I'm getting it now, assuming it has something to do with my apache2 or htaccess but not sure what it would be. I did not change any of my codeigniter files and do not believe the problem lies with CodeIgniter.

EDIT 2: My .htaccess file (domain name edited) looks like this:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Environment Name
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Sets the environment that CodeIgniter runs under.
 SetEnv CI_ENV development

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /


    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Gzip compression
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is it a WordPress website? Try re-saving the permalinks.

Comment: In your pages you have a link to a stylesheet that's broken. Check the exact location of site.css on the server and fix the path in your pages that try to link to the stylesheet.

Comment: It's a CodeIgniter, not a WordPress site. Sorry should've specified that. And @jibsteroos I'll try that but I didn't change any of my html code or file locations so I'm pretty sure it's a configuration problem. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Try with a full path, use something like e.g. $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/css/site.css"; to link to the css file

Comment: @lovelace9 see my edit, thank you!!

Comment: Could you show your .htaccess file, maybe you unintentionally changed it?

Comment: @lovelace, updated question with .htaccess. I tried uploading a back-up and that didn't affect anything.

Comment: Looks fine; you mentioned apache config file, sure you reset it to a default version?

Comment: Fixed it, was a problem with some DNS settings I don't remember changing. Weird. Thanks for the help @lovelace!!

Comment: Glad you got it to work again!